# Linux Deamon in C++ or Java?

Tags: java, c#, c++, linux, daemon

I have a Windows service written by another developer who no longer works with me. It was written in C# with .NET 4.5 requirements. Our solution is making the move to Linux and the daemon naturally needs to be converted.

My dilemma is what to rewrite it in? C++ or Java? The daemon is not complicated. It's simply a controller for our other applications to ensure if they crash or are killed they are restarted. Aside from that it performs health checks through a named pipe and is controlled via a password protected web socket via a separate management Tomcat web interface and writes all of it to logs.

Please put aside any suggestions of "write in what you're most comfortable with" I have a fair amount of experience and knowledge in both languages, and I'll learn whatever else I need to as I go. My concern is the feasibility and effort to accomplish everything I need. I don't have any particular time constraints, but if one language is a fraction of the time of the other then maybe that's a better solution.

Writing it in Java looks like the easiest solution currently, but writing it in C++ has the advantage of being native no-frills code. However, I haven't ever written any web interface or socket code in C++ before, so I do not know the effort involved with that.

To break down my requirements:

- Linux
- Web interface for control
- Named pipe for communicating with client applications
- Existing code needs to be heavily refactored

Is C++ or Java more appropriate?

Edit: added more info

Edit2: I guess I should have mentioned that the code needs to be heavily refactored anyways. It was originally written in such a way that renders it difficult to make changes and additions. So rewriting is a cleaner solution at this point. As I mentioned, it's not a large program. Just a controller service.

Comment: Perhaps you shoud add "C# With .NET Core" to your list as well

Comment: Writing it in Java rather than just leaving it in C# seems easier? I don't get the logic in that. It's already written in C#. What could be easier than leaving it in C#?

Comment: This question looks to be far off topic for this site.

Comment: @itsme86 What Chris is referring to is moving the app from a Windows only solution to Linux.

Comment: @itsme86 well, the fact that C# doesn't work on Linux without Mono. Last time I checked Mono didn't support anything above .NET 2.0 and the C# code requires .NET 4.5

Comment: Unless your program involves a lot of direct interaction with hardware, I would go with Java.  If you look at the numbers of tags on StackOverflow.com (http://stackoverflow.com/tags), which can be a reflection of how active the respectively community is, you have these numbers (as of today 2016-12-22): Java: 1,186K; C++: 488K.

Comment: @Chris .NET Core is somewhat new, but it's cross-platform.

Comment: @Chris Maybe you have a better chance to get your question opened again if you say "I have requirements x,y, what are the pros and cons for either language". ... Other than that, please don't require a JVM instance for such a small background thing. (edit: Ah, now I'm reading about the web UI... not as small and simple as I thought before)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Porting the solution to .Net Core may the way to go. It will run on Linux (and Mac for all intents and purposes...) and most of your codebase may need minimal refactoring. The only concern is if .Net Core currently has the features you would need supported in the app. And, .Net Core is still in preview.

Comment: "Preview" might be a bit of a misnomer, I'm pretty sure at least 1.0 if not 1.1 is RTM. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/11/16/announcing-asp-net-core-1-1/

Comment: @BradleyDotNET You're right, but that only applies to ASP.NET Core which is a modular framework that runs on . NET and .NET Core. The .Net Core framework is currently in preview 4.

Comment: Looks like the only thing still in preview is the SDK: https://github.com/dotnet/core/releases but you are correct that the versions don't necessarily line up

Comment: I wish they would have picked a little more cohesive naming and versioning  process. Or have a table displaying what is currently what without half-guessing. But, things are moving in the right direction for .NET at least.

Comment: No doubt; they did at least do that for .NET standard versions!